# How to provide the iOS local notification through the Xamarin.Forms?

Tags: ios, xamarin, notifications, cross-platform, alert

I'm new in in mobile development and Xamarin. 
I'm trying to provide cross-platform local notifications via DependencyService.

I'm using Xamarin's tutorials for specific-platform(for iOS in this example):

https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/application_fundamentals/notifications/ios/local_notifications_in_ios_walkthrough/

So the problem is that when i press the button nothing happens.
My code:

`ContentPage`:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Tasker
{
    public class TestPage : ContentPage
    {
        StackLayout layout = new StackLayout();
        public TestPage ()
        {
            var notifyButton = new Button
            {
                Text = "Notethat",
                VerticalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
                HorizontalOptions = LayoutOptions.CenterAndExpand,
            };
            layout.Children.Add (notifyButton);

            notifyButton.Clicked += (sender, e) => {
                DependencyService.Get<INotification>().CreateNotification();
            };
            this.Content = layout;
        }

    }
}
```

Then I've created interface for my cross-platform injection:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Tasker
{
        public interface INotification
        {
            void  CreateNotification();
        }

}
```

OK. Then I implement my Notification interface for iOS:

```
using System;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Tasker.iOS;
using UIKit;
using Foundation;
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(INotification_IOS))]
namespace Tasker.iOS
{
    public class INotification_IOS:INotification
    {
        public INotification_IOS ()
        {
        }
    public void  CreateNotification()
        {
            // create the notification
            var notification = new UILocalNotification();

            // set the fire date (the date time in which it will fire)
            notification.FireDate = NSDate.FromTimeIntervalSinceNow(1);

            // configure the alert
            notification.AlertAction = "Some info";
            notification.AlertBody = "Your one minute alert has fired!";

            //notification.

            // modify the badge
            notification.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

            // set the sound to be the default sound
            notification.SoundName = UILocalNotification.DefaultSoundName;

            // schedule it
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ScheduleLocalNotification(notification);

        }
    }
}
```

Then my AppDelegate class. I think that problem is somewhere here:

```
using Foundation;
using UIKit;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace Tasker.iOS
{
    [Register("AppDelegate")]
    public class AppDelegate :global::Xamarin.Forms.Platform.iOS.FormsApplicationDelegate
    {
        private UIViewController viewController;
        private UIWindow window;
        public override bool FinishedLaunching(UIApplication app, NSDictionary options)
        {
            global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init ();//you can't remove it

            viewController = new UIViewController();
            window = new UIWindow ();


            window.RootViewController = viewController;
            window.MakeKeyAndVisible();


             //check for a notification
            if (options != null)
            {
                // check for a local notification
                if (options.ContainsKey(UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey))
                {
                    var localNotification = options[UIApplication.LaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey] as UILocalNotification;
                    if (localNotification != null)
                    {
                        UIAlertController okayAlertController = UIAlertController.Create (localNotification.AlertAction, localNotification.AlertBody, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
                        okayAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
                        viewController.PresentViewController (okayAlertController, true, null);

                        // reset our badge
                        UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
                    }
                }
            }

            if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (8, 0)) {
                var notificationSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes (
                    UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound, null
                );

                app.RegisterUserNotificationSettings (notificationSettings);
            } 
            LoadApplication (new App ());//if you will remove it, app won't be launched
            return base.FinishedLaunching (app, options);
            //return true;
        }

        public override void ReceivedLocalNotification(UIApplication application, UILocalNotification notification)
        {
            // show an alert
            UIAlertController okayAlertController = UIAlertController.Create (notification.AlertAction, notification.AlertBody, UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert);
            okayAlertController.AddAction (UIAlertAction.Create ("OK", UIAlertActionStyle.Default, null));
            viewController.PresentViewController (okayAlertController, true, null);

            // reset our badge
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.ApplicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

So as you see i tried to make cross-platform local notification.

Exactly cross-platform function "CreateNotification()" works - I checked.

So the problem is somewhere where I create Alert or window for notification.

Will be grateful for any help!

Comment: Did you put any breakpoints in your code? Do they get hit?

Comment: Yes, it goes through the method,through the EVERY line of code in the method CreateNotification() , but it has no connection with "AppDelegate". It seems like AppDelegate should work and catch those events by such methods like ReceivedLocalNotification(), but I'm not experienced to know the exact architecture of that. Can you point me, why method ScheduleLocalNotification(notification) for example doesn't have any result on app?

Answer (score -2):

You could try this plugin that is PCL

https://www.nuget.org/packages/Xam.Plugins.Notifier/

Comment: Apart from the link, please provide a short snippet of code explaining how to use that plugin.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this, but there are one error : System.MissingMethodException-------Method 'NSDate.op_Implicit' not found. What does it mean? Why it's missing, couldn't you explain please? Maybe, some old methods are using in this plugin, or I use it in wrong way?

Comment: I've created a blank new project. Checked for all references and dependencies and this method is still missing. Did you tried it before?